# executing script only when script is in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, viewport

How could I execute a JavaScript, on a page, only when the script itself it is in the browser viewport, meaning: imagine I have a script at the bottom of the page and I would like that script to load only when the user scroll the page all the way to the end.

I have found some stuff if you want to load images, but not for scripts:

http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

Any Idea if that's possible at all?

cheers

Comment: Scripts don't really "enter the viewport". Use something as a target element in the DOM, monitor its position, execute when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger scripts on the basis of HTML/DOM elements visiblity as scripts does not actually get into the viewport of the device. You can do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($("element").scrollTop() == 0) { // or some other value, I am taking 0 which means when the element has 0px distance and is currently visible

// Do some action here

}
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean? to add my script inside a DIV and reference the div:

if($("div:mydiv").scrollTop() == 0) { 
// Do some action here

}
</script>

Comment: No, Actually I mean you can trigger the script whenever some HTML element is visible on the screen. When a user scrolls to a particular part of the webpage, you can trigger your scripts using the above code. The above code means that when the $("element") is reached on the page while scrolling.

Also, I would like to tell you that you can not lazy load scripts like the images, but still you can defer them using the "defer" attribute in the script tags. If you write the script tags in the footer section, it will be loaded when your footer code is parsed by the web browser.

Comment: hey zafar, I tried that but it wont work. :(  I am testing with a simple alert: "alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");" without success. thats why I was asking if I should change the element. I am also loading: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js